# Set the iteration count for DEF

Tags: data-exchange-framework

I am wondering where in code to update the Entities submitted. I would have expected the `Iterate Data and Run Pipeline1` pipeline to handle the count with each iteration. But mine stays 0 all the way through.

Sitecore 9.1
DEF 2.1

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to track this down. You can just add `pipelineContext.PipelineBatchContext.CurrentPipelineBatch.GetPipelineBatchSummary().EntitySubmitedCount += 1;` to your pipeline, but I have several pipelines and several that are reusable. So I made my own pipeline to handle the incremental update of the count.

#### The converter

This basically does nothing but handle my custom pipeline template (`{4F1AACC2-BC1D-41EC-AB49-D21A2F78D661}`)

```
namespace Sitecore.Feature.Def.Converters.PipelineSteps
{
    using Sitecore.DataExchange.Attributes;
    using Sitecore.DataExchange.Converters.PipelineSteps;
    using Sitecore.DataExchange.Models;
    using Sitecore.DataExchange.Repositories;
    using Sitecore.Services.Core.Model;

    [SupportedIds(TemplateId)]
    public class IncrementBatchPipelineStepConverter : BasePipelineStepConverter
    {
        public const string TemplateId = "{4F1AACC2-BC1D-41EC-AB49-D21A2F78D661}";
        public IncrementBatchPipelineStepConverter(IItemModelRepository repository) : base(repository)
        {
        }

        protected override void AddPlugins(ItemModel source, PipelineStep pipelineStep)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

#### The processor

This is where I add the `EntitySubmitedCount`

```
namespace Sitecore.Feature.Def.Processors.PipelineSteps
{
    using Sitecore.DataExchange.Contexts;
    using Sitecore.DataExchange.Models;
    using Sitecore.Services.Core.Diagnostics;
    using Sitecore.DataExchange.Extensions;
    using Sitecore.DataExchange.Processors.PipelineSteps;

    public class IncrementBatchPipelineStepProcessor : BasePipelineStepProcessor
    {
        protected override void ProcessPipelineStep(
            PipelineStep pipelineStep,
            PipelineContext pipelineContext,
            ILogger logger)
        {
            pipelineContext.PipelineBatchContext.CurrentPipelineBatch.GetPipelineBatchSummary().EntitySubmitedCount += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Sitecore.DataExchange.Plugins.PipelineBatchSummary** class has a property **EntitySubmitedCount**

This property is used in **ShowPipelineBatchStatusCommand**:

```
PipelineBatchSummary pipelineBatchSummary2 = pipelineBatchSummary1;
          DateTime dateTime;
          if (pipelineBatchSummary2 != null)
          {
            dateTime = pipelineBatchSummary2.RequestedAt;
            str = Environment.NewLine + Translate.Text("Entities submitted: {0}", (object) pipelineBatchSummary2.EntitySubmitedCount);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> statuse in pipelineBatchSummary2.Statuses)
              str = str + Environment.NewLine + statuse.Key + ": " + statuse.Value;
          }
          else
            dateTime = DateTime.Now;
          TimeSpan timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow - dateTime;
          Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Alert(Translate.Text("{0} started at {1} and is running on {2} server for {3}.", (object) contextItem.Name, (object) DateUtil.FormatShortDateTime(dateTime), (object) "local", (object) timeSpan.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss")) + str);
          Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Timer(string.Format("item:load(id={0})", (object) contextItem.ID), 2);
```

Where is increased this property?

In the class: **Sitecore.DataExchange.Providers.XConnect.Processors.PipelineSteps.BaseSubmitXConnectBatchStepProcessor** it's next  method:

```
protected virtual void OnBatchProcessed(
      Guid batchId,
      ICollection<IXdbOperation> operations,
      PipelineContext pipelineContext,
      IXdbContext client = null)
    {
      if (operations != null)
        pipelineContext.PipelineBatchContext.CurrentPipelineBatch.GetPipelineBatchSummary().EntitySubmitedCount += operations.Count<IXdbOperation>((Func<IXdbOperation, bool>) (o =>
        {
          if (o.Status != XdbOperationStatus.Succeeded)
            return o.Status == XdbOperationStatus.Created;
          return true;
        }));
      if (!this.VerificationLogEnabled(pipelineContext.PipelineBatchContext.CurrentPipelineBatch))
        return;
      if (operations != null)
        this.SetVerificationLogStatuses(pipelineContext, operations);
      this.SubmitVerificationLogEntries(pipelineContext);
    }
```

where EntitySubmitedCount is increased.

This method is called from method SubmitBatch:

```
protected virtual void SubmitBatch(
      string batchDescription,
      IXdbContext client,
      PipelineStep pipelineStep,
      PipelineContext pipelineContext,
      ILogger logger)
    {
      if (client == null)
      {
        this.SubmitVerificationLogEntries(pipelineContext);
      }
      else
      {
        string[] logDetails = this.GetLogDetails(batchDescription, client, pipelineStep, pipelineContext, logger);
        if (!this.ShouldSubmitBatch(client, pipelineStep, pipelineContext, logger))
        {
          this.Log(new Action<string>(logger.Info), pipelineContext, "Batch will not be submitted to xConnect.", logDetails);
          this.SubmitVerificationLogEntries(pipelineContext);
        }
        else
        {
          try
          {
            this.Log(new Action<string>(logger.Info), pipelineContext, "Submitting batch to xConnect.", logDetails);
            IRetryerOnException retryer = this.GetRetryer(pipelineStep, pipelineContext, logger);
            if (retryer == null)
              client.SubmitAsync().Wait();
            else
              retryer.Retry((Action) (() => client.SubmitAsync().Wait()));
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
            pipelineContext.CriticalError = true;
            throw new XConnectClientException("Exception while submitting batch to xConnect.", ex);
          }
          this.OnBatchProcessed(client.LastBatchId, (ICollection<IXdbOperation>) client.LastBatch, pipelineContext, client);
        }
      }
    }
```

SubmitBatch method is called inside some PipelineSteps.

I hope it helps you my answer.